# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I can't post my images, please help!

Code for reference

```
var config = require("./config.js");
var Twit = require('twit');
var I = new Twit(config);

var images = [
  { 
    file: './api/images/img_1.png',
   
  },
  { 
    file: './api/images/img_2.jpg',
    
  },
]

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

upload_image();
 
function upload_image(images){
    console.log('Opening an image...');
    var image_path = path.join(__dirname, './images'),
        b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64', media_type: "image/png" });
    console.log('Uploading an image...');
    I.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, uploaded )
    function uploaded (err, data, response) {
      var id = data.media_id_string
      var tweet = {
          status: "This is an image",
          media_ids: [id]

      }
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
        //console.log(response);
      };
      I.post('statuses/update',{ status: tweet }, tweeted)
      function tweeted(err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Success: ' + data.text);
          //console.log(response);
        }
    }
    }
  }

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>     
> errno: -4068,  
> syscall: 'read',  
> code: 'EISDIR'

Please help, I don't know what I'm doing, please!

I don't have anything to say please help, Indians please!
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is on the lines `var image_path = path.join(__dirname, './images'),
        b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64', media_type: "image/png" });`.  You set `image_path` to the name of a directory, and then attempt to read that directory as if it were a file.